# Why are the crew members of the Covenant less vigilant than those of the Prometheus?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

When crew members of the Prometheus land on a new planet, they are wearing eco-suits that isolate themselves from the outside atmosphere. [image]

But ten years later, when crew members of the Covenant land on a new planet, they are not.[image]

This is illogical as people are aware of the potential danger when exploring a new planet, let alone the Prometheus' unexplained disappearance.

Comment: In prometheus the air of the planet was not breathable.